# Execute a file via keyboard in Finder

Tags: finder

I have a Finder window open to a directory that contains files. They have an associated application to them.

What key combination can I hit to have the selected file opened in its default application?
What's the equivalent of double-clicking that file with the mouse?

I don't want to have to take my hands off the keyboard.

I have tried without success:

- Cmd Enter
- Ctrl Enter
- Option Enter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd-O</kbd> opens the file in its default application.

Also, <kbd>Cmd-P</kbd> opens the file and starts the print dialog (not supported by all applications).

Comment: that and **Cmd**-⬇ (down arrow)